# Finding minimum path from source to destination by changing height of squares

Tags: algorithm, path, shortest-path

We have NXM grid. One square of the grid is source and one is destination. Each square of grid including source and destination have some elevation(an integer from value 0-9). **We have to find a minimum cost path** from source to destination satisying following restrictions:

1. The path must be continuous i.e. between adjacent squares only (not diagonal adjacency).
2. One can go from higher elevation to lower elevation only.

The elevation of any square can be increased or decreased. The amount by which elevation changes is counted as cost. If elevation does not change, it is taken as **zero** cost.
So total cost of path from source to destination is the change in elevations of the squares that comes in the path. Moreover **elevation of source can't be changed but that of destination can be**.

I tried to apply some algorithm like Djikstra and APSP but could not reach any solution. Please help me in this problem.

Comment: is the height changing something that must be done before traversal, so the change is made, to create the optimum landscape, and then the traversal is made, or is it something that is done *during* traversal, so that a square that the path has already passed over may change height during traversal?  it's not clear to me that the second case is useful/important, as it is only different from the first for a path that "goes backwards" at some point (i think), but it seems like an important distinction to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of simple shortest distance problem with another dimension, try to formulate the problem like this,
cost[n][m][max_height] = {INFINITY};

cost[srcX][srcY][ height[srcX][srcY]  ] = 0;

now cost[x+1][y][ht] = min(cost[x+1][y][ht],  cost[x][y][q_ht] + (q_ht - ht) )   for q_ht varies from max_height to ht. The idea is to reach at (x+1,y,ht) with least cost from any allowable heights(ie height >= ht). This again we need to calculate for for all ht(0 to max_height). The full implementation is down here:-

```
#define HIGHVAL 100000000
#define XI (x + a[i])
#define YI (y + b[i])

int n,m;

bool isvalid(int x,int y)
{
    return (x>=0 && y>=0 && x<n && y<m);
}

int main()
{

    int pondX, pondY;
    int farmX, farmY;

    cin>>n>>m>>pondX>>pondY>>farmX>>farmY;
    pondX--, pondY--, farmX--, farmY--;

    int height[n][m];
    string s;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>s;
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            height[i][j] = (int)(s[j] - '0');
    }

    int ht = height[pondX][pondY];
    int cost[n][m][ht+1];
    bool visited[n][m];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<ht+1; k++)
                cost[i][j][k] = HIGHVAL;

    cost[pondX][pondY][ht] = 0;
    int a[4]= {0,0,1,-1};
    int b[4]= {1,-1,0,0};

    int ci = pondX, cj = pondY;
    queue<int> qx;
    queue<int> qy;

    visited[pondX][pondY] = 1;

    memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited));
    qx.push(pondX);
    qy.push(pondY);

    while(qy.size())
    {
        int x = qx.front();
        int y = qy.front();

        qx.pop();
        qy.pop();

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            if(isvalid(XI, YI))
            {
                if(!visited[XI][YI])
                {
                    qx.push(XI);
                    qy.push(YI);
                    visited[XI][YI] = 1;
                    temp = 1;
                }

                for(int j=ht; j>=0; j--)
                {
                    int q = HIGHVAL;
                    for(int k=ht; k>=j; k--)
                    {
                        q = min(q, cost[x][y][k] + abs(j - height[XI][YI]));
                    }

                    if(cost[XI][YI][j] > q)
                    {
                        cost[XI][YI][j] = q;

                        if(visited[XI][YI] && !temp)
                        {
                            qx.push(XI);
                            qy.push(YI);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    int ans=HIGHVAL;
    for(int i=0; i<=ht; i++)
        ans = min(ans, cost[farmX][farmY][i]);

    cout<<ans;
    //cout<<" "<<n<<m;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may consider that the elevation of the destination square can't be changed either, since there's no need to elevate it.

Now, in classical Dijkstra(-like) algorithm you'd say that every square of your grid has a *price* at which you can reach this square. That is, your source square has *price*=0, Then in a loop you take the next *cheapest* square and try to move from it to all the adjacent squares, whose price is bigger.

In your problem you have an extra degree of freedom: the elevation level of your square. That is, when you move to a square you are allowed to change its height.

The most straightforward "brute-force" solution would be the following:

1. Check all the cells, build a set of their elevation levels (i.e. the
   spectrum of all the heights). Say you have **H** distinct heights.
2. Define the state of the square as its position **and** height. The define your problem in terms of Dijkstra graph.
3. For every square add a vertex to the graph that represents its actual elevation. Then add extra vertexes that represent it with a bigger elevation (besides source and destination squares). So that you have up to **H** vertexes for every square.
4. Define an *internal price* of every vertex as its height above its actual position. So that for every square you have a vertex with *internal price*=0 (the actual elevation), plus number of vertexes representing elevated positions with appropriate *internal price*.
5. Connected vertexes representing neighbor squares by **directed** edges. Put an edge only if the source vertex has an elevation at least of the target vertex.

Then find the shortest path by Dijkstra (or A*) algorithm. The *cost* of the move is considered the *internal price* of the target vertex (our edges don't carry the price).

In simple words we've built a "layered" graph, each layer corresponds to an optional height. At each position you're allowed to make a move either at your current layer, or get lower.

Needless to say that the problem complexity increases. The vertex count is increased by the factor of (up to) **H**, the same holds for the edges count.

Basically the path-search has the complexity of `log(N) * N * M` where **N** is squares cell count, and **M** - is the connectivity orders (number of connected nearest neighbors). After your inflation the complexity grows by (up to) the factor of **H^2**.

So that the efficiency of this algorithm depends on the number of distinct heights. If you have a small number of heights - the algorithm should be efficient. However if all your squares have distinct heights - perhaps another approach should be used.

Comment: Yeah, this approach will do but for small values of H,N,M. It would be better if some more efficient algorithm is there.

Answer (score 0):

The "changing elevation" *appears* to complicate the problem at first, but if you think about it a bit more carefully, it doesn't really. First, there is no reason to ever decrease the elevation of a square -- only increase. And there is never any reason to elevate any square but the "end" square for the current "branch" of the search. **AND**, in any traversal, there is never any reason to increase the elevation of a square beyond the amount needed to make it possible to move to the next square. I might add that an optimal path will never loop back on itself. So at each step of the search, the square which should be elevated, and how much to elevate it, is completely deterministic. You do not need to use search to find that out. So the "layered graph" which @valdo proposed is not actually necessary.

With that insight, you can use almost any standard path-finding algorithm in a straightforward way.

Comment: Wait a minute, I just realized something. When it is necessary to increase/decrease elevation, you can *always* get an optimal path by *elevating the "current" square*, rather than decreasing the elevation of the square where you want to go. That makes the problem even simpler.

Comment: Well, I didn't notice that the elevation may be decreased as well (I thought it can only be increased). Nevertheless, it'll not always be optimal. Imagine an 1-dimensional example, where there's a single path from source to destination. Source square has height=2, next square has height=0, next 100 squares have height=1, and the last (destination) square has height=0. According to "your" algorithm you get down on the 2nd square to height=0, and then lower the next 100 squares. However a better alternative would be to raise the 2nd square to height=1.

Comment: @valdo, that's what I pointed out in the comment preceding yours. It was confusing for me to put that information in a comment rather than editing the answer... I have now edited the answer for clarity.